# While Loop Fuction

Tags: sql, t-sql, for-loop, sql-server-2008, while-loop

I have this query

```
 select         
 Suc,       
 SKU,       
 TipoMov,       
 Prov,      
 sum(Uni) as Uni, sum(Imp_Vta) as Imp_Vta 
 into #Mov 
 from dual where (Mes between 22009 and 22105) 
 and        Suc = 11 
 and        TipoMov in (4,5,8)
 and        Id_Fec_Diaria between '2020-09-28' and '2021-05-17' 
 group by 
 Suc,       SKU,        TipoMov,        Prov
```

and I'm trying to do a while loop between two dates
so far I have this but there is a mistake I can't fix nor understand.

```
declare
@FechaMin DATE='2020-09-28',
@FechaMax DATE='2021-05-17';

while (@FechaMin >= @FechaMax)
begin 
        select 
        suc,
        SKU,
        TipoMov,
        Prov,
        sum(Uni) as Uni,
        sum(Imp_Vta) as Imp_Vta
into #Mov
from dual
where (Mes between 22009 and 22105) and
        Suc = 11 and
        TipoMov in (4,5,8) and
        Id_Fec_Diaria >= @FechaMin and Id_Fec_Diaria< @FechaMax
group by 
        suc,
        SKU,
        TipoMov,
        prov) END
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When does your while loop end? How do you take care that it is not running forever?

Comment: Why are you using a `WHILE` at all? SQL is a set based language, the last thing you want to be using is an iterative solution.

Comment: You can't use `select ... into` in a loop like that. The statement creates the table `#Mov`, so in the next iteration you will get an error because the table already exists.

Comment: Also SQL Server 2008 had been completely unsupported for over 2 years; long past time to have sorted your upgrade paths.

Comment: Selecting `from dual`, are you sure it's not Oracle?

Comment: Why are you using a while loop at all? What are you hoping to do? All your question is, right now is "hi guys, i have this and it is broken: (nonsense code). How do i fix it?" - we can't tell you, because you *haven't said what you want, you've only said what you have* (and what you have is so broken it's not possible to deduce from it what you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken about your purpose, you have to use **cursor** to achieve your goals.

You can replace your `while` block with this code:

```
DECLARE 
    @Suc VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @SKU   VARCHAR(MAX),
    @TipoMov VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Prov VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Mycursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
         Suc , 
         SKU ,
         TipoMov,
         Prov 
    FROM 
        dual where (Mes between 22009 and 22105) 
 and        Suc = 11 
 and        TipoMov in (4,5,8)
 and        Id_Fec_Diaria between '2020-09-28' and '2021-05-17'

OPEN Mycursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Mycursor INTO 
    @Suc , 
    @SKU   ,
    @TipoMov ,
    @Prov ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -----Your Specific Code
        FETCH NEXT FROM Mycursor INTO 
             @Suc , 
             @SKU   ,
             @TipoMov ,
             @Prov ;
    END;

CLOSE Mycursor;

DEALLOCATE Mycursor;
```